# How often we should call connection close in doctrine2 query?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

How often we should call connection close in doctrine2 query? Does this this effect performance of the application?

```
$em->getConnection()->close();
```

Comment: never? When you close the connection every operation done with the em will fail....